# Tensorflow on Android via Kivy

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, kivy

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34495029/828184) that brought me to the idea instead of using the compiled tensorflow graph you might be able to use kivy on your Android phone. That way you could directly talk to the tensorflow graph using [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android).

A possible advantage would be to train/adapt the model on the fly. As far as I know otherwise you can only use the final trained model (but this is currently [unanswered on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242881/is-it-possible-to-train-tensorflow-on-android)). Also cross compiling to Windows Phone might be possible what currently isn't (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270450/tensorflow-on-mobile-devices-android-ios-windows-phone/40330084?noredirect=1#comment67916191_40330084)).

I don't know the technical limitations. Anyone can confirm that this is possible and maybe what would be neccessary?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although WinPhones *could* be a possibility in the future, there's basically a situation where almost no-one cares as there isn't really much interest about porting it. However, there's a thing in progress about using `angle` for translating openGL to DirectX, so it could be possible *later*. There's still this funny app packaging though, so it'll eat a lot of time.

Yet I think it might be possible to use those unofficial converters APK -> WinPhone app. Re TensorFlow: to me it looks like only a recipe is missing so [try write one](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes). :P